# Update count of an item stored in a database

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm setting up a point of sales system with counts of products in stock. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get my method to update the quantities of one of my products.

I can execute the query in the command line with a value and it will update the count of the product. The count is stored in the text property of txtBanCount here.

```
namespace POSSystem
{
  public partial class POSsystem : Form
  {  
    public POSsystem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    MySqlConnection conn;

    private void MySqlConnect()
    {
        string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;database=possystem;port=3306;password=bhuytr83";
        conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
    private void UpdateQuantities()
    {
        string banSqlUpdate = "Update Products SET count = '" + txtBanCount + "' + WHERE prodName = 'Bananas';";
        MySqlCommand cmdBanUpdate = new MySqlCommand(banSqlUpdate,conn);
        cmdBanUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

I expect the 'Count' column of my Products table to be set to the text displayed on txtBanCount.

Comment: I assume the extra + character may have something to do with this. Also don’t put numbers in quotes and learn to use parameters instead of concatenating strings for SQL. It helps with this also.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that `txtBanCount` is a text control right, so use it's Text

> property **txtBanCount.Text**

so please use below code

```
private void UpdateQuantities()
{
    string banSqlUpdate = "Update Products SET count = '" + txtBanCount.Text + "' WHERE prodName = 'Bananas';";
    MySqlCommand cmdBanUpdate = new MySqlCommand(banSqlUpdate,conn);
    cmdBanUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to have worked. I tried this as well...             string banSqlUpdate = "Update Products SET count = 29 WHERE prodName = 'Bananas';";
            MySqlCommand cmdBanUpdate = new MySqlCommand(banSqlUpdate,conn);
            cmdBanUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: I got it to work. I closed the connection earlier so I just removed that line of code

Comment: Concatenating a string that the user has typed, into an SQL, is a universally terrible idea. Please see http://bobby-tables.com for more info, and consider changing your answer to use parameters